# CM Database Upgrade from SDL 2013 SP1 to SDL 9.1

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2

We have a SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 ( Java DXA) website running on Oracle 12.1 c 12.1.0.0). We are in the process to update SDL 9.1 and done following:

1) Exported the current CM Database and imported in new DB server Oracle 12.1 C
2) While running the powershell script to upgrade the CM Database getting the error as image attached.

[image]

Please advice.

Thank you.

Comment: I would contact Customer Support for something like this. You may have applied a hotfix on the DB (or manually changed the DB?) that altered the schema and the upgrade script can't cope with that change.

Comment: Nuno - you should give that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you can upgrade directly from Tridion 2013 SP1 to Site 9.1,  the documentation states the following;

> "If you perform a non-rolling upgrade, you can upgrade to the current
>   version of SDL Tridion Sites (formerly called SDL Web or SDL Tridion)
>   from the following versions: SDL Tridion Sites 9 SDL Web 8.5

What I have done in the past was to run the PowellShell script to upgrade to SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1, then you have two options, upgrade to Web8.5 or upgrade to Site 9. when you are in any of these two versions you should be able to upgrade to site 9.1.